# Is it possible to await a function that doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, fetch-api

I have a for loop that fetches code from another file and appends it to my website using the `insertAdjacentHTML()` method. After that it modifies the innerHTML of the freshly added piece of code. My current solution looks something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fetch("myFile.html")
    .then((obj) => obj.text())
    .then((text) => {
        document.getElementById("addContentHere").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text);
        document.getElementsByClassName("elementInAddedContent")[i].innerHTML = "Modified content";
    });
}
```

In my website I have the following code:

```
<div id="addContentHere"></div>
```

And the HTML that I'm fetching is something like this:

```
<div class="addedElement">
    <div class="elementInAddedContent"></div>
</div>
```

So the end result in my website should look like this:

```
<div id="addContentHere">
    <div class="addedElement">
        <div class="elementInAddedContent">Modified content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="addedElement">
        <div class="elementInAddedContent">Modified content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="addedElement">
        <div class="elementInAddedContent">Modified content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course all added elements are going to have different content, but for example purpouses I'm keeping it simple. The problem is that the computer reaches the `document.getElementsByClassName("elementInAddedContent")[i].innerHTML = "Modified content";` before the element has been added and so I get the `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')` error. Can I somehow use await on code that doesn't itself return anything? So something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fetch("myFile.html")
    .then((obj) => obj.text())
    .then((text) => {
        await document.getElementById("addContentHere").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text);
        document.getElementsByClassName("elementInAddedContent")[i].innerHTML = "Modified content";
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping the same file over and over?

Comment: Also never loop Ajax, especially not if you want the browser to have time to change the DOM

Comment: @mplungjan I am loading the same content, but modifing it differently according to the data in a javascript object.

Comment: That makes ABSOLUTELY no sense

Comment: Assuming you are fetching the same URL each time, then the for loop should probably be inside the last `then`

Comment: Please post example HTML from the page, example HTML you are fetching and expected output

Comment: @mplungjan suppose you have to dynammically add multiple cards to your website, each with different data, but same overall design.

Comment: If all the cards are from the same HTML, then I would read it ONCE and then scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is trying as fast as possible to read a file, update the DOM and read again and update again. There is no control over what is happening since Fetch is async. I still do not understand why you had a loop around getting ONE file..

Perhaps you meant to do this?

I give the DOM 100 ms to be updated

```js
fetch("myFile.html")
  .then((obj) => obj.text())
  .then((text) => {
    document.getElementById("addContentHere").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text);
    setTimeout(() => document.querySelectorAll(".elementInAddedContent").forEach(el => el.textContent = "Modified content"), 100);
  });
```

Comment: Any way for it to not be an arbitrary delay?

Comment: What do you mean? The DOM needs a few milliseconds to not choke on the next statement

Comment: I mean that it might be waiting longer than needed.

Comment: Not likely. 100ms is not a lot. 10ms is the smallest you can use